# Wireless only semi-working with Lenovo Ideapad S10-3t netbook (driver Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller)

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom, lenovo

Wi-fi in this laptop was working perfectly with 11.10 version of Ubuntu.

Now, with 12.04.2 or 13.04 it only works with some networks. It works with WEP but I haven't been able to make it work with WPA.

Been looking for a solution but most of them tell you to add some lines to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf, and I guess in my case doesn't help because my ubuntu already comes with that file, with the following content:

```
# Warning: This file is autogenerated by bcmwl. All changes to this file will be lost
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma
```

So, anybody knows how to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Is your device 14e4:4727? lspci -nn. Is your driver wl? lsmod. I believe wl is incorrect for your device. Please confirm before we propose a solution.

Comment: thanks for your comment, yes it is 14e4:4727. lsmod | grep wl returns: lib80211  14352  2 wl,lib80211_crypt_tkip \n cfg80211  510937  1 wl

Comment: my guess is that you're going to propose that I do: `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source && sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`?

Comment: Excellent guess, except I doubt you need the firmware part. Please proceed and please let me and the searchers hear your report.

Comment: thanks, I'll test it now (but unfortunately I've found this page which has the row "no (WIP)" in the row that maps to my PCI-ID: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43 )

Comment: after doing `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source` NetworkManager doesn't see any networks. `lsmod | grep brc` returns `brcmsmac 550698 0\n cordic 12574 1 brcmsmac \n brcmutil 14755 1 brcmsmac \n mac80211 606457 1 brcmsmac \n cfg80211 510937 2 brcmsmac,mac80211 \n bcma 41051 1 brcmsmac`, should I do `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer` next?

Comment: Did you try a reboot? Do you have a wireless interface wlan0? iwconfig Does it scan? sudo iwlist wlan0 scan Is the switch on or off? rfkill list all

Comment: Yes I had tried rebooting. Red herring, I think after the 2nd reboot and deleting previous NetworkManager profiles, it started working. So I summarized all this tinkering in a new answer (but there I asked a final question). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @chili555's first pointer, I could dig enough and fix my problem. So I'll summarize it here (and post a final question).

There are three kind of Broadcomm wifi drivers that apply to this situation (taken from [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless)):

<kbd>**Driver**</kbd>                         <kbd>**Description**</kbd>                                                           
  <kbd>broadcom-wl</kbd>              <kbd>Proprietary Broadcom STA driver</kbd>                          
  <kbd>b43</kbd>                             <kbd>Reversed engineered (open source) kernel driver</kbd>
<kbd>brcmsmac/brcmfmac</kbd><kbd>Open source Broadcomm kernel driver</kbd>

So, apparently, Ubuntu came pre-installed with `broadcom-wl` enabled. As this [Kernel spec page says](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43), the b43 is not an option (it says "No (WIP)") for my hardware ID `14e4:4727`, and the alternatives are wl and brcm80211 (the latter got renamed to **brcmsmac**). So then simply removing the package of the proprietary driver will make the brcmsmac start working (without installing any additional package because, as it is open source, this driver is embedded in the kernel):

`sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source`

After rebooting and deleting my previous network-profiles saved in NetworkManager, this started working.

So, now the question is, how to fix this upstream so Ubuntu 13.10 comes without the proprietary driver package installed in case it finds this hardware?